# Parallelization of user fetching with graph api and delta

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I user delta query to get changes to users for a particular tenant. The algorithm looks like:

1. Fetch all users and save delta
2. Use delta to get only changes

Everything works fine however the initial call to fetch all users is very slow, as I need to follow nextLink and basically if a tenant has hugh number of users ( > 1 000 000) and max number of items per page is 999 it takes a lof of the for that synchronization.
I thought, I could parallelize it - use startswith(mail,'{a}') filter and call the api for every letter in the alphabet. The problem is that with this approach I cannot fet delta link (or I would get a delta for every call).
Is there maybe a better way to speed up user fetching ?

Comment: Have you tried performing the initial fetch of users with the listing API (GET on /users with filters running in parallel, but not delta) and at the end performing a single delta call will ?$deltatoken=latest ? If yes did you notice a performance difference? Note: this approach doesn't guarantee consistency of data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/migrate-azure-ad-graph-feature-differences#differential-queries

Comment: I haven't tried. Sounds very interesting, thank you very much for the tip.

Comment: another way to make it faster without parallelization would be to select only the properties you absolutely need.

Comment: I already download only the properties needed, but thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 0):

Delta on users does not support filtering objects today on any other property than the Id. You could request support for filtering by adding an idea in [UserVoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com).

As a workaround you could sync the users in parallels with a filter using the GET API (/users) and then issue a delta query with $deltatoken=latest to get a token from that point and not have to sync all the changes sequentially. This doesn't guarantee consistency though.

Lastly, sync can be made faster (using delta, without parallelization) by selecting only the properties you need.